# Why is spring data jpa repository.save performing an insert and an update one after the other on the same entity?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring data jpa app with Hibernate/Hikari/Hazelcast. The setup is similar to [this demo project](https://github.com/xmlRoot/spring-data-demo) . The issue I am experiencing in my production code is that when a `JpaRepository.save` is invoked I get an insert and then an update on the same entity. What I mean is, when we call

```java
parents.save(parent)
```

Where `parents` is a repository instance, the generated queries are :
`insert into child(id, name, parent_id) values (?,?,?)` and immediately after
`update child set name=? parent_id=? where id=?`,
I fail to see why this is happening. We will be saving around a thousand or more entities at a time and I am trying to minimize the unnecessary DB queries.

I would love it if someone can help out with some ideas why such a behavior is observed. The demo project resembles the actual setup in terms of entity relations, mappings and transactions. `open-in-view` is set to false, no explicit `@Transactional` annotations are used.

The problematic behavior is not observed in the demo project. I can't unfortunately share the production code here.

Thanks,

Comment: Please show your `parent` entity mapping.

Comment: it's in the [demo project](https://github.com/xmlRoot/spring-data-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/dbdemo/entities/Parent.java)

Comment: @JensSchauder It actually helped thanks, I managed to fix it, when I removed the cascade=ALL from my relationship in conjunction with the suggestion from the question you've mentioned it started working. In short, removing the cascade and letting the child entity persist/handle the relationship, removed the redundant update statement.